# TYPO3: Can't use Variables from REGISTER in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typoscript

Upgraded Website to TYPO3 V. 10. With this changed from rtehtmlarea to ckeditor. Works well. But I used data from REGISTER as Variable in the RTE text: {REGISTER:heute}. But now there is no output. The corresponding Typoscript-Setup was(is)

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.innerStdWrap_all.insertData = 1

tt_content.text.12 = LOAD_REGISTER
tt_content.text.12.heute = TEXT
tt_content.text.12.heute {
        data = date:U
        strftime = %d.%m.%Y
}
tt_content.text.21 = RESTORE_REGISTER
tt_content.text.22 = RESTORE_REGISTER
```

Is there a similar easy solution with ckeditor?

Comment: You can write a plugin for CKEditor to insert the date with a javascript function.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I am a nonprofessional without real javasciptknowledge.